# How to show excerpts from pg-search multisearch results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I've set up pg_search in my Rails app on Heroku:

```
@query = 'fast'
PgSearch.multisearch(@query) #=>
[#<PgSearch::Document searchable: ferrari, :content: 'this car is really fast'>,
 #<PgSearch::Document searchable: viper, :content: 'a very fast car'>]
```

I'd like to display these results with excerpts from `content` to show where the match occurs. I can call `excerpt(content, @query)` to get exactly what I want when `@query` is only one word, but `excerpt()` only handles exact matches, so if:

```
@query = 'car fast'
PgSearch.multisearch(@query) #=>
[#<PgSearch::Document searchable: ferrari, :content: 'this car is really fast'>,
 #<PgSearch::Document searchable: viper, :content: 'a very fast car'>]
```

then `excerpt(content, @query)` is nil because nowhere in `content` does the exact phrase 'car fast' appear.

I considered `excerpt(content, @query.split(' ').first)` to at least show *something* for multi-word queries, but there are still cases such as this:

```
@query = 'car?'
@results = PgSearch.multisearch(@query) #=>
[#<PgSearch::Document searchable: ferrari, :content: 'this car is really fast'>,
 #<PgSearch::Document searchable: viper, :content: 'a very fast car'>]
excerpt(@results.first.content, @query) #=> nil
```

So, how do folks show excerpts from search results when using pg_search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW— Following nertzy's example above, I was able to get this to work with the following:

```
PgSearch.multisearch(@query).select("ts_headline(pg_search_documents.content, plainto_tsquery('english', ''' ' || unaccent('#{@query}') || ' ''' || ':*')) AS excerpt")
```

I was having trouble getting `plainto_tsquery(?)` to work, as it was throwing a syntax error.  My solution above was simply the result of doing

```
PgSearch.multisearch(@query).select(["ts_headline(pg_search_documents.content, plainto_tsquery(?)) AS excerpt", @query]).to_sql
```

and then plugging in the `to_tsquery` arguments for the new `plainto_tsquery` call—something I'm sure is not entirely sound, but seems to work.

Comment: That first block of code worked for me. Thanks for the answer Sirvine, and thanks to Nertzy for pointing us in the right direction and for the excellent pg_search gem!

Comment: Isn't that first code block subject to sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author and maintainer of pg_search.

Right now there isn't a built-in way to get excerpts along-side your results in pg_search, but there easily could be if I or someone else has the time to build it in.

PostgreSQL has a function [ts_headline](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE) that you can call which returns a string excerpt as a column.

It might be possible to call something like this (I haven't tested it yet):

```
PgSearch.multisearch(@query).select(["ts_headline(pg_search_documents.content, plainto_tsquery(?)) AS excerpt", @query])
```

Then each of your results should have an `excerpt` method that returns something like what you want.

By the way, this is something that I eventually want to make automatic in pg_search. I just haven't had the time to delve too deeply into it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpolate the string, you will be subject to sql injection attacks.

Since the `.select` won't accept a parameterized statement like the `.where` does (`Users.where("id = ?", params[:id])`), you will need to sanitize explicitly.

```
sanitized = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:q])
@results = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:q])
                  .select(["ts_headline(pg_search_documents.content, plainto_tsquery('english', ''' ' || '#{sanitized}' || ' ''' || ':*')) AS excerpt"])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way, if you don't feel like digging through SQL - you can make use of built in pg_search gem functionality to display excerpts in a really simple and straightforward way:

In your controller:

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight
```

In your view:

```
= raw(article.pg_search_highlight)
```

That should do it.

Comment: This does not work for multisearch, as the question specified.